# iPhone/iPad - issues with NavigationBar button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uinavigationbar

I my application i have added button in NavigationBar like this..

```
UIBarButtonItem *more=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-25by25.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(SelectMission:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = more;
```

When i am clicking on button application get's shutdown...

If i am doing same thing with normal button it's working fine can any one help me why it's behaving like this?

Comment: By "get's shutdown" do you mean it crashes? If so, could you please post the crash log.

Comment: check SelectMission method or put code and crash log here.

Comment: Crash log info - [RootViewController SelectMission]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a23250 2011-01-12 21:06:45.428 TestApplication[1989:207] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RootViewController SelectMission]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a23250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

> UIImage *i=[UIImage
> imageNamed:@"search-25by25.png"];
>
> ```
>   UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
>   myButton.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, i.size.width, i.size.height );    
>   [myButton setImage:i forState:UIControlStateNormal];
>   [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(SelectMission:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
> ```
>
> UIBarButtonItem *more=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
> = more;

hope it helps :)

Comment: Than post the crash log here please :)

Comment: Crash log info - [RootViewController SelectMission]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a23250 2011-01-12 21:06:45.428 TestApplication[1989:207] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RootViewController SelectMission]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a23250

Comment: I guess you have miss typed the method name SelectMission or you have no arguments on it. If you got not arguments, then you should remove the last colons on the action:@selector(SelectMission:). Just use action:@selector(SelectMission)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the code for `SelectMission:`? The code you've posted is only for presenting the button, which from your description appears to be working.

Also if there's anything being dumped into the console (Command-Shift-R)?

Comment: Crash log info - [RootViewController SelectMission]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a23250 2011-01-12 21:06:45.428 TestApplication[1989:207] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RootViewController SelectMission]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a23250

Comment: The SelectMission call in your crash log doesn't have a colon, but in your original example does. Does it accept an argument?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the crash log in your comment, I would say this has nothing to do with the UIBarButtonItem class in particular, and everything to do with your action handler.  The crash logs tell the whole story: Your class does not implement a method called SelectMission: that takes one argument.  Some caveats about the @selector keyword that you will want to double check:

1) Capitalization.  Make sure that the method you implement is SelectMission:. Not selectMission:, selectmission:, Selectmission:, etc.

2) Arguments. The colon indicates that the method SelectMission: takes one argument.  If you have implemented it and forgotten the argument it will crash with the exception you posted.

That should help narrow down the issue.